# php code to show limited text in description

Tags: php, text, limit

```
public static function description()
{      
    if (empty(self::$description)) {
        return self::$config["description"];
    } else {
        return self::$description;
    }
}
```

I am using this to show description for my youtube api script but i want to show some limited text upto 150 characters. I don't know which code should i use to show limited text description

```
<?php echo Main::description() ?>
```

and using the above code in header to show description. please tell me the proper code for showing description upto 150 chr. limit

Comment: You could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php or regex `^(.{1,150})`. Have you tried any trimming solutions yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at php's substring function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

So you could wrap the description in

```
substr($var, 0, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally using a function like this.

```
function my_special_trim($string, $length = 150, $abbreviation = false) {
    $modified = mb_substr($string, 0, $length);

    if(mb_strlen($modified) < mb_strlen($string)) {
        $modified = trim($modified, " \n\r\t.");
        $modified = "$modified&nbsp;&hellip;";

        if($abbreviation) {
            return '<abbr title="'.htmlspecialchars($string).'">'.$modified.'</abbr>';
        }
    }

    return $modified;
}
```

**Edit**: Originally posted a longer function to handle shortening by words. Change to the current one as it was actually referencing other function which was not included. That can be easily achieved, e.g., using `preg_replace` function.